# Completely remove deleted files from Github

Tags: github

I pushed a sensitive file to Github then quickly deleted it. The issue is, the file contents remain in Github as deleted data, but it's still viewable.

Is there any way to permanently remove any and all Git tracking of this data? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: You should consider the information comprised and rotate credentials.

Answer (score 0):

BFG repo cleaner is a great tool to do this: http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Just use the following command after installation:

```
bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE
```